# how to redirect user to their selected option page

Tags: javascript, html

```
<main>
    <div class="container">
        <select name="semester" id="select-semester">
            <option value="no-semester">select semester</option>
            <option value="semester 1">semester 1</option>
            <option value="semester 2">semester 2</option>
            <option value="semester 2">semester 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</main>
```

like i have semester1,semester2,semester3 as option so i want that if anyone select semester 1 then he will move to semester 1 page

Answer (score 2):

I would subscribe to the `change` event of the select, and then, depending on the selected value, would redirect to the appropriate page

something like this:

```
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <select name="semester" id="select-semester">
      <option value="">select semester</option>
      <option value="1">semester 1</option>
      <option value="2">semester 2</option>
      <option value="3">semester 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</main>


document
  .getElementById('select-semester')
  .addEventListener('change', function (this: HTMLSelectElement) {
    var semesterId = this.value;
    if (semesterId) {
      window.location.href = '/semester-' + semesterId;
    }
  });
```

Comment: I don't reccomend you use only the change event, to navigate the user to another page. Place a link below under the select. The value change event replaces the href attribute of the <a> tag. I made an example below...

Comment: I think it's more like just a navigation menu and there is no need for a second user click. in any navigation, we do not first select a menu item and then a button to navigate. we go to another page as soon as we select a navigation item

but it's up to the author of the question. he knows better how it should work from this point of view

Comment: Yeah, you has right, but we don't know the reason why it is important for Rakesh Singh.

Answer (score 0):

I made an example here for you!
I placed a link below under the select. The value change event replces the href attribute of the  tag.

```js
let semester = document.querySelector("#select-semester");
let go = document.querySelector("#go");
semester.addEventListener("change", (e)=> {
    go.href = go.dataset.baselink + semester.value;
    go.innerHTML = "GO to " + semester.value
  }
);
```

```css
#go {
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: gray;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <select name="semester" id="select-semester">
            <option value="no-semester">select semester</option>
            <option value="semester 1">semester 1</option>
            <option value="semester 2">semester 2</option>
            <option value="semester 2">semester 3</option>
        </select>
        <a id="go" href="#" data-baselink="https://www.somelink.do/">GO</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: But I think it is much easier if you placing than 3 link against the select and button or link combo.